# Missing available ftrace tracer types on my device

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, trace, ftrace

I am developing a user-land tracer wrapper for some research and I am needing to look specifically into context switches in my kernel. Going from [this](https://lwn.net/Articles/290277/) LWN article (section under "sched_switch" about a third of the way down) I have noticed some differences between my system's (Android device running a 3.10.9 kernel) output and that of the article (written for a 2.6 kernel). My biggest problem being the lack of next task state. To show exactly, the article's output has a format of

```
sleep-4055  [01]   240.132371:   4055:120:S ==>  3997:120:R
```

(focus on the R at the end to indicate the next state's state)
My output:

```
GLThread 292-7361  [000] d..3  9421.164945: sched_switch: prev_comm=GLThread 292 prev_pid=7361 prev_prio=120 prev_state=R ==> next_comm=surfaceflinger next_pid=3036 next_prio=98
```

Now the resources on the internet are all a bit jumbled and mixed and so I am hoping for some quick clarification.

In the article the trace is configured by

```
echo sched_switch > /debug/tracing/current_tracer
```

Now on my system I do not have this as an available tracer

> odroidxu3:/d/tracing # cat available_tracers
> function_graph wakeup_rt wakeup function nop

but I am able to trace the sched_switch event through the following interfaces

> $cat available_events | grep sched_switch
> sched:sched_switch
>
> $ls events/sched/ | grep switch
> sched_switch

Which leads me to ask, does my kernel lack some functionality that needs patching (similar to this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590513/linux-kernels-ftrace-output-format) post) or has the ftrace interface moved sched_switch from an available tracer to a ftrace event?

If it does require patching where can one find a compiled list/on-going list of ftrace patches?

Cheers